# implement tunnel between two golang channels

Tags: go, channel

I am trying to implement a tunnel between two go channels (note I am very new to go). My goroutine looks like this:

```
consumer := ...
producer := ...
go func() {
    for jsn := range producer {
        msg, err := ops.FromJSON(jsn)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
            continue
        }
        consumer <- msg
    }
}()
```

This though seems to have some issues. How can I check if the consumer is already closed? How to solve the race between getting the message from the producer and sending it to the consumer? ... and maybe others.

Can someone provide a good example of a tunnel between two channels?

Comment: `consumer` shouldn't be closed in this situation. Why do you consider receiving a message, processing it, then sending the response a "race" here?

Comment: if I read a message from the producer and consumer is incapable to handle it, I cannot return it back to the producer to be handled from another consumer. Since this is not an atomic operation - it is in race with any other thread that could put the consumer in a state that prevents it to handle the message (in privite closing it)

Comment: What do you mean by "tunnel" between two channels?